# How to do Seq.takeWhile + n items in F#

Tags: f#

This is piggybacking on the classic question [how to do Seq.takeWhile + one item in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562327/how-to-do-seq-takewhile-one-item-in-f) by extending it to the general case of extracting n items after the predicate returns false.

The obvious bare-bone solution may be based on [Tomas'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12564899) answer to the original question by equipping the recursive loop on `IEnumerator<'T>` with an additional counter, but I can think of at least two other approaches.

First there's `Seq.pairwise` suggested by [Be Brave Be Like Ukraine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12563708) which could be replicated as often as needed; the overhead of the additional tuples will probably mean that it's not very efficient:

```
// Trivial case for n = 0
let takeWhile pred =
    Seq.map (fun t -> pred t, Some t)
    >> Seq.takeWhile fst
    >> Seq.choose snd

let takeWhile1 pred =
    Seq.map (fun t -> pred t, Some t)
    >> Seq.append (Seq.singleton (true, None))
    >> Seq.pairwise
    >> Seq.takeWhile (fst >> fst)
    >> Seq.choose (snd >> snd)

let takeWhile2 pred =
    Seq.map (fun t -> pred t, Some t)
    >> Seq.append (Seq.singleton (true, None))
    >> Seq.append (Seq.singleton (true, None))
    >> Seq.pairwise
    >> Seq.pairwise
    >> Seq.takeWhile (fst >> fst >> fst)
    >> Seq.choose (snd >> snd >> snd)

[1..7] |> takeWhile ((>=) 3) |> Seq.toList
// val it : int list = [1; 2; 3]
[1..7] |> takeWhile1 ((>=) 3) |> Seq.toList
// val it : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4]
[1..7] |> takeWhile2 ((>=) 3) |> Seq.toList
// val it : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
```

---

The other involves deconstruction of the sequence by `Seq.tryHead` and `Seq.tail`. After testing I realize that this would be sub-optimal as the number of times the elements of the sequence get evaluated grows quadratically.

```
let takeWhileN pred n source = 
    let rec aux i source = seq{
        match Seq.tryHead source with
        | Some x when pred x && i = 0 ->
            yield x
            yield! aux 0 (Seq.tail source)
        | Some x when i < n ->
            yield x
            yield! aux (i + 1) (Seq.tail source)
        | _ -> () }
    aux 0 source

[1..7] |> takeWhileN ((>=) 3) 0 |> Seq.toList
// val it : int list = [1; 2; 3]
[1..7] |> takeWhileN ((>=) 3) 1 |> Seq.toList
// val it : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4]
[1..7] |> takeWhileN ((>=) 3) 2 |> Seq.toList
// val it : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
```

Can this be improved upon?

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is very good.  The only note is that once you're past the predicate, you can use `Seq.truncate` rather than yielding items one at a time.

```
let rec takeWhileN pred n source = seq {
    match Seq.tryHead source with
    | Some x when pred x ->
        yield x
        yield! takeWhileN pred n (Seq.tail source)
    | _ -> yield! Seq.truncate n source            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just be direct about it:

```
let takeWhileN pred n source =
    let matches = source |> Seq.takeWhile pred |> Seq.length
    source |> Seq.truncate (matches + n)
```

Comment: This evaluates the sequence twice, which is much better than my quadratic second attempt.